# What i need to Change here in my List<> on employee object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

This is my employee object

```
      public class Employee : BaseEntity
{        
    public Employee()
    {
        this.HistoryOfStatuses = new List<Checkinout>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Checkinout ActualCheckinStatuse { get; set; }
    public List<Checkinout> HistoryOfStatuses { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; internal set; }
    //test
}
```

}

This is my Controller

```
   HistoryOfStatuses = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                        join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                        where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                        orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                        select new Checkinout
                        {
                            CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                            CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                         }).ToList()
```

This is my Checkinout class

```
     public class Checkinout: BaseEntity
{
   public Checkinout() {
    }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string CheckStatus { get; set; }
   public DateTime CheckTime { get; set; }
   public Employee EmployeeObject { get; set; }

}
```

And this is my view i cant use the CheckStatus or CheckTime

[This is my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIR6s.png)

Comment: Please include that error message in your screenshot as part of your question rather than in a link

Comment: Include the code for Checkinout class

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_loops.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can see, your HistoryOfStatuses is a list, so you shouldn't be calling for a property of the list, you should be first doing an iteration of your list and then access the property of the current iterated object.

So you might need to do a foreach loop. Ex:

```
@foreach(var history in item.HistoryOfStatuses){
    <h1>@history.CheckStatus</h1>
}
```

Comment: This was all what i needed Thank you Man.

Answer (score 1):

`HistoryOfStatuses` is a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), which does not have a property of `CheckStatus`.

You need to pick an item from the list before you use the `CheckStatus` property.

Something like,

```
item.HistoryOfStatuses[0].CheckStatus
```

That is assuming you want the first record in the list, which may not be what you want. But the point is that you need to pick an item from the list or loop through the list.